# spliting a string using linq queries in C# from fist name to last name

Tags: c#, linq, split

The name would be a single string like string NAME="BILL GATES"
the plan is to order it in the last name first then the first name last so 
Gates Bill, what's happening is that it's coming out as first and last.

```
var Q4 = from p in persons
                 orderby p.Name.Split()[1], p.Name.Split()[0]
                 select p;
        foreach (var Item in Q4) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Item}");
        }
```

Comment: You don't say what the problem is, but don't `select p` if `p` is not what you want.  If you want "a single string like string NAME='BILL GATES'", then `select` that instead.  Also, a [`let` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) would simplify your `orderby` and be more efficient, too.

Comment: Calling Name.Split in the order by wont save the split string, it simply splits the Name so it can use it for the orderby and then scraps that split string. You can split it in the query where you select the Name.Split()[0] and [1], or you can split it in the foreach loop after the query is done. Then when you output it, you use the last name before using the first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198894/spliting-a-string-using-linq-quiers-in-c-sharp-from-fist-name-to-last-name/61199171#comment108264850_61198894) pointed out in the comments, you need to [`select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/select-clause) the new name(last name + firstname) after you sort with [`orderby`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/orderby-clause). Additionally, this can be made easier storing the split names once with the [`let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) clause, which is also more efficient since you don't need to re-split the names every time you want to use them.

```
var Q4 = from p in persons
         let names = p.Name.Split()
         orderby names[1], names[0]
         select new { Name = $"{names[1]} {names[0]}" };
```

The above also uses [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to insert the last name before the first name into a space separated string. You can also use `names[1] + " " + names[0]` here if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

`orderby` will not replace the content in "Name". If you want change the content, use `select new`:

```
       var Q4 = from p in persons
                select new
                {
                    name = p.name.Split()[1] +" "+ p.name.Split()[0]
                };

        foreach(var Item in Q4)
        {
              Console.WriteLine($"{Item}");
        }
```

Comment: The question is "what am I doing wrong?" Your answer should address this specifically and then, optionally, suggest how it should be done. A code dump isn't a good answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not performing the ordering as requested by and demonstrated in the question.  Also, this would be a good opportunity to fix the redundant `Split()` calls.

Comment: @BACON - In the example mentioned in the question you would like to do: to change the words - "BILL GATES" to "GATES BILL" (you must call Split() twice) and this what my code doing.

Comment: I'm not the question author, but I took it to mean that reordering the first and last names is to be done _in addition_ to the `orderby` already present in the code.  I suppose it's ambiguous if the output is supposed to be ordered by last name then first name, or if the use of `orderby`  was just an attempt to produce the new text.  Also, you don't need to call `Split()` more than once and it's inefficient to do so.

Comment: @בינהכהן - What does `orderby` actually do then? Your answer is still very sparse and unclear.

Comment: @Enigmativity order by actualy for sort items into array with linq sentence. But it does not sort the string itself

Comment: @BinaCohen - That should be in your answer. Don't make people read your comments to find out if the answer is good or not.